# Check if the Checkbox with the Value X gets unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(!$('input:value').is(:checked)){

//do something

}
```

How do i do this, i can´t find an example?
I want to know if a checkbox with a specific value has been checked.

Comment: You can use the [attribute value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Do you want to check every time it's checked status is changed, or only at runtime? In one way or another, using this expression will perform the check for you: `$('input[value="X"]').not(:checked)`. However, if you want to check its value whenever its state is being updated, you will need to bind an event listener to it.

Comment: Okay, if i have a variable called x, can i do this? $('input[value=x]').not(:checked)

Answer (score 0):

loop through checkboxex 
and then check as below

```
var c=$(".commonclassname");
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
   if(c[i].value=="your value")
   {
     //matched...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to detect if a checkbox with a particular value gets unchecked

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "test2" && !$(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Unchecked Test2");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwm28b7u/1/